# ASP.NET Web API - Why are my User's Email Claim always returned emtpy?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my app I am creating my Authentication Controller.

On a login, if the credentials are valid, I create a JWT to which I want to append some custom claims, defined as such:

```cs
List<Claim> claims = new()
            {
                new Claim("name", userModel.UserName),
                new Claim("email", userModel.Email),
                new Claim("id", userModel.Id),
            };
```

If I Log each of my claims separately, or check the generated Token, I can see all my claims as part of the payload.

However, if I send my token to a protected route, and try to find those claims as such: (inside my protected controller)

```
var username = User.FindFirst("name").Value!;
Console.WriteLine($"username {username}");

var userId = User.FindFirst("id").Value!;
Console.WriteLine($"userId {userId}");

var userEmail = User.FindFirst("email").Value!;
Console.WriteLine($"userEmailClaim {userEMail}");
```

the `userEmail` is always empty.

The others work as expected.

Here's my code, for more explicit context:

```cs
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UserModel>> Login([FromBody] UserLoginModel model)
        {

            string email = model.email;
            string password = model.password;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Login {email}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Password {password}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Login {email}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Password {password}");
            var userExist = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => email == user.Email);
            if (userExist == null || userExist.Email != email)
            {
                return BadRequest("Login Information does not match our records");
            }
            var hasher = new PasswordHasher<UserModel>();
            if (PasswordVerificationResult.Failed == hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(userExist, userExist.PasswordHash, password))
            {
                return BadRequest("Login Information does not match our records");

            }
            string token = CreateToken(userExist);

            return Ok(token);

        }

        private string CreateToken(UserModel userModel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"userModel.Email {userModel.Email}");
            List<Claim> claims = new()
            {
                new Claim("name", userModel.UserName),
                new Claim("email", userModel.Email),
                new Claim("id", userModel.Id),
            };

            // Key used to create the JWT and verify the JWT, whenever user's make a call.
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"claims {claim}");

            }

            //Need a signing credentials
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
                signingCredentials: creds
                );

            //write token
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
            return jwt;
        }

        [HttpGet, Authorize]
        public ActionResult<string> GetUserName()
        {
            var username = User.FindFirst("name").Value!;
            Console.WriteLine($"username {username}");

            var userId = User.FindFirst("id").Value!;
            Console.WriteLine($"userId {userId}");

            //var userEmail = User.FindFirst("email").Value!;
            var userEmailClaim = User.FindFirst("email");
            Console.WriteLine($"userEmailClaim {userEmailClaim}");

            //if (userEmailClaim != null)
            //{
            //    var userEmail = userEmailClaim.Value;
            //    // Handle userEmail as needed
            //    return Ok(new { userEmail });
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    // Handle the case where the "email" claim is missing.
            //    return BadRequest("The 'email' claim is missing.");
            //}
            return Ok(new
            {
                username,
                userId,
                //userEmail
            });
        }
```

Comment: Null and empty are different mutually exclusive things.  More importantly, you should provide some convincing evidence that it should not be null nor empty

Comment: The first line in `GetUserName` references a variable `User` - where is that defined and populated?  It's neither a parameter nor a local variable.   Also what version of .net / asp.net are you working with?

Comment: `User` here is from the ClaimsPrincipal ControllerBase.User. I am using .NET 7

Answer (score 0):

We should use [`IClaimsTransformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation) to implement this.

MyClaimsTransformation.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class MyClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var claimType = "myNewClaim";
        if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == claimType))
        {
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, "myClaimValue"));
        }

        principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Registe it as a service.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformation>();
```